# Draw perfect vertical line in C using font

Tags: c, windows

I have one old system developed in C where we cannot draw vertical lines. I use the pipe symbol (|) repeated which looks like a vertical line but it give a little gap in between, as shown below.

```
|
|
|
|
```

Is there any other character which don't give gap. I also tried Windows Character Map, there are characters but still there is minor gap.

Comment: This has absolutely __nothing__ to do with the C language.

Comment: It depends upon what your "old system" monitor is. But there may be some higher character codes above 128 that do "box" drawing characters.  See under DOS in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character). As @MichaelWalz says, this has nothing to do with whatever programming language you're using. If you know the name/type of your system, that would be a reasonable tag if it exists here.

Comment: Use [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) ?

Comment: `magic_move_to(5.f, 0.f); magic_line_to(5.f, 20.f)`. Otherwise just accept the fact that you are drawing ASCII art.

Comment: [ASCII 179](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-codes/box-drawings-single-vertical-line-character-ascii-code-179.gif), html entity &boxv; or Unicode U+2502. It should look something like this: │.

Comment: @Groo That's great. But still it will give gap in between